# R sapply/lapply with multiple ifelse statements

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply, sapply

I'm trying to simplify the following multiple ifelse code using sapply or lapply (still can't distinguish them).

My goal is to allocate points based on placement like shown below.

```
df$Point <- ifelse(df$Placement_v2 <= 1, 10,
ifelse(df$Placement_v2 <= 10, 9, 
ifelse(df$Placement_v2 <= 25, 8,
ifelse(df$Placement_v2 <= 50, 7, 1) )))
```

This code works okay, but I want to make a dataframe and simply my code above using sapply or lapply (or anyother function).

I've tried this code but is not working as expected. Only the rows with placement 1 get 10 points and other rows end up with 1.

<2nd code>

```
df$Point <- sapply(df2$Placement, function(x) ifelse(df$Placement_v2 <= x, df2$Point[df2$Placement == x], 1 ) )
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dataframe with values and replacements. Then you can use `cut` to lookup the appropriate value

```
dict = data.frame(replacement = c(10, 9, 8, 7, 1, 1),
    values = c(0, 1, 10, 25, 50, 1e5))

#DATA
set.seed(42)
placement = sample(1:100, 15)

cbind(placement,
    new_placement = dict$replacement[as.integer(cut(placement, breaks = dict$values))])
#     placement new_placement
# [1,]        92             1
# [2,]        93             1
# [3,]        29             7
# [4,]        81             1
# [5,]        62             1
# [6,]        50             7
# [7,]        70             1
# [8,]        13             8
# [9,]        61             1
#[10,]        65             1
#[11,]        42             7
#[12,]        91             1
#[13,]        83             1
#[14,]        23             8
#[15,]        40             7
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code worked nicely. I just wanted to learn more about the cut function. my levels are shown as (1,10] (10,25] (25,50] (50,100] (100,200] (200,1e+07]. Is there a way to make it like 1] (1,10] (10,25] (25,50] (50, 100] (100, 200] (200 ? I'm trying not to use 0 or 1e5 in my data frame.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to go about this. I'll use `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.table(Placement_v2 = runif(200, -10, 100))
```

First option, move the evaluation out to a function, and then `lapply` the function to your `Placement_v2` column. This has the benefit of being much cleaner than your nested `ifelse` statements.

```
funky <- function(x) {

  if (x <= 1) {
    val <- 10
  } else if (x <= 10){
    val <- 9
  } else if (x <= 25){
    val <- 8
  } else if (x <= 50){
    val <- 7
  } else {
    val <- 1
  }

  return(val)

}

df[, Point := unlist(lapply(Placement_v2, funky))]
```

Result:

```
     Placement_v2 Point
  1:    21.633527     8
  2:    76.713565     1
  3:    34.987461     7
  4:    87.131914     1
  5:    93.451401     1
 ---                   
196:    41.318597     7
197:    34.751585     7
198:    62.515336     1
199:     6.758128     9
200:    53.015376     1
```

I would instead approach this by subsetting the data, and assigning by each subset. You could do this by specifying each subset `df[Placement_v2 <= 1]`, `df[Placement_v2 >= 1 & Placement_v2 <= 10]`, etc. But, if you do it in the correct order, you can avoid the double equality evaluation.

```
df[, Point := 1]
df[Placement_v2 <= 50, Point := 7]
df[Placement_v2 <= 25, Point := 8]
df[Placement_v2 <= 10, Point := 9]
df[Placement_v2 <=  1, Point := 10]
```

Which gives the same result:

```
     Placement_v2 Point
  1:    21.633527     8
  2:    76.713565     1
  3:    34.987461     7
  4:    87.131914     1
  5:    93.451401     1
 ---                   
196:    41.318597     7
197:    34.751585     7
198:    62.515336     1
199:     6.758128     9
200:    53.015376     1
```